# How is ordered a Dictionary in Pharo?

Tags: dictionary, collections, smalltalk, pharo

Let's say we have a loop that enters `Association`s to a `Dictionary` in a clear order:

```
| d |

d := Dictionary new: 10.

1 to: 10 do: [ :i |
    d add: i -> (i + 9 printStringBase: 20)
].

d
```

When I evaluate this code I get a `Dictionary` in a "twisted" order:

```
9 -> I
5 -> E
1 -> A
10 ->J
6 -> F
2 -> B
7 -> G
3 -> C
8 -> H
4 -> D
```

Each time a `Dictionary` with the same entry data is created it have the same order, so I assume it is a feature not a bug ..?

I use Pharo v9.0.21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75007256/4081336) is is worth explaining the apparent disorder shown in the question.

Firstly observe that `Dictionary new: 10` will create a new instance of `Dictionary` with capacity for a prime number `p` of associations greater than `10`. Say 11, 13, 17, whatever.

Secondly, for every association added, the dictionary will compute the hash value of the key and deduce the location from its remainder modulo `p`.

Since all keys occurring in the example are instances of `SmallInteger`, their hashes will be themselves(*). And since these are smaller than `p`, they will equal the modulo and hence be stored in the slots derived from their values in some implementation-dependent way.

Finally, the printing method is free to enumerate the associations in any order.

---

(*) While this is true in some dialects, I've checked in Pharo and this is not true, `3 hash` is not `3` etc. which explains the "twisting" in the case of Pharo.

Comment: Hm, that's surprising. I was assuming that the `Dictionary` constructor will work similar to an `Array` constructor. Is there some important reason to why are Associations distributed this way and not the way they been entered by a programmer?

Comment: Yes, dictionaries are hashed collections, and the way they are constructed statistically minimizes the lookup, which is O(1) in the majority of cases, precisely because hashed collections avoid linear search (as much as possible).

Comment: Smalltalk seems to have much more optimization oriented features then I though

Comment: Smalltalk has much more capabilities than most people think. Not their fault though.

Comment: I just wander, how is a `Dictionary` initialized? Inside it's class there is no initialization method. Inside it's super class (`HashedCollection`) the initialization method is taking argument `n` and allocation an instance array with `n` size, that what made me think that `Dictionary`'s initialization works the same as in `Array`'s

Comment: A `Dictionary` has two ivars `array` and `tally`. As you can see in the code (or even better debugging the expression `Dictionary new: 10`), the initialization proceeds by first finding the appropriate prime number, and then relying in the initialization inherited from `HashedCollection`, which creates the supporting `array` and sets `tally` to `0`.

Comment: @siery a `Dictionary` is a very fundamental data structure, present in basically every programming languages. They're actually quite hard to implement, if you want to do it right, but having an efficient implementation of `Dictionary` is not Pharo-specific.

Answer (score 6):

A Dictionary is not an ordered collection. Instead it is a keyed collection, keeping key-value pairs.

There is an OrderPreservingDictionary for you to use: https://github.com/pharo-contributions/OrderPreservingDictionary

Comment: If it is not ordered so what is going on at the example above? Is that a bug?

Comment: @siery You should probably understand how `Dictionary` is implemented to understand why the order sometimes is consistent, sometimes not. A `Dictionary` is a hash map, which is based on a hash function (or a family of hash functions, depending on the implementations) which may or may not require some randomness to work. All this to say: it's hard to understand *exactly* why the order of elements in a dictionary is what it is. You should just not rely on it, because it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @siery: The fact that `Dictionary`'s contract does not guarantee a consistent ordering does not mean that there aren't specific circumstances running a specific piece of code on a specific version of a specific implementation on a specific platform where the ordering may *appear to be* consistent. It just means you are not allowed to rely on that ordering. If you book a vacation and the terms of service say that sunshine is not guaranteed, that doesn't mean it will be raining all the time. It just means you can't complain if it does.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness of the answer there is such thing as ordered Dictionary.

At [Smalltalk/X](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smalltalkx/info) the `#OrderedDictionary` is defined as:

```
Dictionary subclass:#OrderedDictionary
        instanceVariableNames:'order'
        classVariableNames:''
        poolDictionaries:''
        category:'Collections-Sequenceable'

"/     I am a subclass of Dictionary whose elements (associations) are ordered in a
"/     similar fashion to OrderedCollection.
"/     That is, while being filled via #at:put: messages (or similar Dictionary protocol),
"/     the order in which associations are added, is remembered and accessible via the #atIndex:
"/     or #order messages. 
"/     Therefore, this combines fast access via hashing with a defined order when enumerating.
"/     
"/     [instance variables:]
"/         order <OrderedCollection>       Ordered collection of keys reflecting the order of
"/                                         associations in the dictionary.
"/ 
"/     [complexity:]
"/         access by index: O(1)
"/         access by key: O(1)
"/         searching: O(n)
"/         insertion: mostly O(1)
"/         removal: mostly O(N) (because order will have O(n) behavior)
"/         
"/     [author:]
"/         Ifor Wyn Williams 
"/         Changed by: exept
```